# Can canvas and silver-tape withstand the pressure difference in The Martian?

Tags: the-martian

In the movie The Martian, after Mark screws the HAB's airlock, he seals the hole using a plastic canvas and some silver-tape. After that, he repressurizes the HAB.

Is this feasible and realistic? Would the canvas and the silver-tape be able to withstand the difference in gas pressure? If so, for how much time? Also, how could he repressurize the HAB with an Earth-like atmosphere if all the air leaked out in the accident?

Comment: It wasn't simply tape and canvas.  It was HAB material and sealant tape made specifically for sealing leaks.

Comment: It worked in both the book/movie, so yes, it works in that universe.

Comment: Questions asking if movie-science is "realistic and feasible" are out of scope for this site.

Comment: Seems like this question "relates directly to a cited work of fiction". Especially given the work in question makes an effort to be scientifically accurate. So I'm not sure how this would be considered off-topic. Regardless, it seems like the best Stack Exchange site to refer the questioner to would be https://space.stackexchange.com/, not one of the science sites.

Comment: It wasn't "silver tape".  It was _duck tape_ (aka _duct tape_)!  The tape of the gods! P.S. I wouldn't have thought this was off-topic because it directly related to the cited work of fiction.

Comment: The Hab would HAVE to have a pressurized vessel of gases for it to realistically be able to work an airlock. As the airlock would vent (a small amount of) atmosphere every cycle, without a gas vessel to replace the gases, the hab would eventually run out of air.